# Не получается ковертировать .ui файл в .py.Выдает "pyuic5" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Не знаю как решить данную проблему,пробовал и переустанавливать pyqt5, также добавил в переменную path путь до папки scripts, ничего из этого не помогло.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если возникают ошибки с  `pyuic5`, попробуйте написать из консоли это (при этом находясь в папке со скриптом)(Windows) :

```
python -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic -x [filename].ui -o [filename].py
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ, который был дан выше у меня вызывал ошибку. Я решил проблему чуть по-другому. Объяснение для полных чайников, каким раньше был я. Только для Windows.
В папке, где лежит ui файл, нужно вызвать командную строку (в проводнике в строке пути удаляете все, вбиваете cmd, нажимаете enter), устанавливаете pyqt5 (pip install pyqt5). Теперь смело можно вбивать команду конвертации прямо в этой же командной строке (pyuic5 file.ui -o file.py). Готово!

Comment: Извините, но в ответе в скобках указано, что это решение для Windows

Comment: Я наверное вас не понял, но мое решение также для Windowd